# I need to migrate this Doclist code to Drivapp, but couldn't

Tags: google-apps-script

I just tried to replace Doclist by Driveapp to perform a file search with parameters `(num,num)` but it returns an error : `invalid method getFiles(num,num)`.

```
function b(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var resultado = ""
  var urlBase = "https://docs.google.com/a/escuelasanpedro.com/file/d/";
  var doc = DocsList.getFolderById("0B8p4BFVjx9pDZXFIYUQzSFZqeFE").getFiles(0,500)
  var idDoc =""
  var nombre =""
  for ( var i = 1; i < doc.length;i++) { 
       if (e.parameter.userName == doc[i].getName().substring(0,doc[i].getName().indexOf("."))) { 
          idDoc = doc[i].getId()
          nombre = e.parameter.userName
          resultado = urlBase + idDoc ;
          }
       }
```

I tried this following code but got the message "function 'getname' cannot be found in iterator objetct"

```
function b(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
//serverhandler, proceso real

  var resultado = ""
  var urlBase = "https://docs.google.com/a/escuelasanpedro.com/file/d/";

  var doc = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B8p4BFVjx9pDZXFIYUQzSFZqeFE").getFiles()
  var idDoc =""
  var nombre =""

 while (doc.hasNext()) {
   var file = doc.next();
       if (e.parameter.userName == doc.getName().substring(0,doc.getName().indexOf("."))) { 
          idDoc = doc.getId()
          nombre = e.parameter.userName
          resultado = urlBase + idDoc ;
       }
 }
```

Comment: @snickers10m which external libs? Dont see any

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation on how to use driveapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it... Your `doc` variable is the iterator, your new variable called `file` is the actual file but you don't use it.

Update like this :

```
 while (doc.hasNext()) { 
 var file = doc.next();
 if (e.parameter.userName == file.getName().substring(0,file.getName().indexOf("."))) { idDoc = file.getId()
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly fine. I need a link where to find more driveApp examples, that would be superb!

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer. Thanks. There are examples on this site but I would suggest trying to see the logic of it, then you won't need examples anymore.